# how to do this in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

i am a beginner in laravel and i need to do this : 
i have a "mgs" table and is this table i have "user_sender" & "user_reciver"
so , how i get informations of this users from "users" table ?

and please correct me this code :

```
$read_msg_user = DB::table('mdg')
                            ->where('user_sender', '=', $id)
                            ->where('vue', '=', 0)
                            ->join('users', 'messages.user_sender', '=', 'users.id')->get();
```

thank's

Comment: Have you tried implementing this is Eloquent (Laravel's ORM), it would certainly make this easier for you. :)

Comment: help me to do it please

Comment: It's quite a large task, but I'd suggest reading this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326950/define-laravel-eloquent-relations-between-3-models-in-a-messaging-system) SO post and the Eloquent docs at http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent.

Comment: Learning PHP, Laravel, Eloquent, as easy as it seems to an expert; to a beginner, it is certainly not easy.  Especially if it is a quite a large task.  @Nassim:  while it will not be of immediate help with your task, it will be good to go over a tutorial that uses Laravel with Eloquent, and maybe find some good webcasts aimed towards beginners.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use mdg instead of messages in your join. mdg.user_sender like this.

```
DB::table('mdg')
                        ->where('user_sender', '=', $id)
                        ->where('vue', '=', 0)
                        ->join('users', 'mdg.user_sender', '=', 'users.id')->get();
```